# Cannot access the web site from a mobile device, using the new URL shown on web server

Tags: javascript, webserver, service-worker

I have build my first web application following the code labs example "Your First Progressive Web App" 
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/

Everything works well, but when I try to access the web server from my mobile device through the local network, I can not see the web app open in my android device.

I have checked the web server IP(192.168.0.161:8887) and my android device IP(192.168.0.231) are in the same local network; also I have selected "accessible on local network" in chrome web server.

Could you please tell what are the possible reasons cause this issue?

Thanks

Comment: And the other way your able to access is?... And what is the tech stack? Where are the configs you used.

Comment: If you can set the web server's port, try changing it to 80. If that works, it's most likely a firewall issue.

Comment: thanks it is a firewall issue!

Answer (score 0):

This is a firewall issue. When I turn off the firewall, I can access the web server from my android phone.

Thanks!